# Using Codeigniter application on freeBSD system

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, freebsd

I have freeBSD installed on IBM server. There is also apache, php and mysql installed on the server. A PHP application running on this machine is working just fine, but our new version of the same application developed in Codeigniter gives a "Page Not Found" error.

The thing is the application is accessible and runs well (only the non-english character are displayed not well) if the `index.php` is included in the url.

I have modified the file `.htaccess` to remove the `index.php` from the url, I kind of need to use the `.htaccess` in the application's root directory. This (using `.htaccess`) is actually causing the error.

Please let me know what configuration do I need to do.

Edit:
Bellow is the content of `.htaccess` in the root directory of the application:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /football/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: could you provide a dump if said `.htaccess`?

Comment: I updated the question @Thomas

Comment: Could this be the solution: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-apache-on-freebsd-10-1#configure-apache-to-allow-url-rewrites